# What is the correct way of testing a POST endpoint that accepts a POJO and a MultipartFile[] attachment?

Tags: java, spring, mockmvc

I'm new to MockMVC. I've successfully written some basic tests, but I got stuck on trying to test an use case with the endpoint that requires a POST request with two parameters - a POJO and an array of MultipartFile. The test is written as such:

```
 @Test
 public void vytvorPodnetTest() throws Exception {
 var somePojo = new SomePojo();
 
 somePojo.setSomeVariable("test_value");
 
 var roles = List.of("TEST_USER");
 var uid = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001";
 
 MockMultipartFile[] attachments = {new MockMultipartFile("file1.txt", "file1.txt", "text/plain", "file1 content".getBytes()),
 new MockMultipartFile("file2.txt", "file2.txt", "text/plain", "file2 content".getBytes())};
 
 MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder builder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/some-pojo/create");
 builder.with(req - {
 req.setMethod("POST");
 return req;
         });
 
 MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(builder.file(attachments[0]).file(attachments[1])
                 .param("SomePojo", new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(somePojo))
                         .file(attachment[0])
                 .with(TestUtils.generateJWTToken(uid, roles)))
                 .andExpect(status.isOk())
                 .andReturn();
 }
```

The controller method is as follows:

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/create", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
 public UUID createPojo(
             @RequestPart(value = "SomePojo") SomePojo somePojo,
             @RequestPart(value = "attachments", required = false) MultipartFile[] attachments) {
 
 return pojoService.create(somePojo, attachments);
  }
```

It stops here, before reaching the service. I've tried adding the files both as a param "attachments" and like shown above, but all I get is "`400 Bad Request`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the way to send the parameters as MockMultipartFile from MockMVC to the controller:

```
MockMultipartFile pojoJson = new MockMultipartFile("SomePojo", null,
            "application/json", JsonUtils.toJSON(podnet).getBytes());

    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/some-pojo/create")
                    .file(pojoJson)
                    .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
                    .with(new TestUtils().generateJWTToken(uid, roles)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
```